# Magento 1.7 How to use categories as filters?

Tags: magento, filter, navigation, magento-1.7, layered

Sorry for my bad english.

I've tried to find, witouth success, how to use existing categories as filters.
So it would let to filter products by all the categories they belong to.

Exemple, I've 3 categories : "brands", "sports" and "categories".

I have a baseball ball appearing in theses 3 categories.

In :

Brands
--- my brand

Sport
--- Baseball

Categories
--- Balls

I would like that, for exemple, if I'm in "my brand" cat, I can filter by "balls", so that I can browse balls from this brand.

I know I can achieve this with attributes, but I don't like the way attributes are ordered, and I wish I could find a way to keep categories tree.

In fact, I want exactly the same filters that we have when we do a research (all categories, and attributes).

Thanks in advance for your helpful lights !

Comment: Sorry to be boring, I want to clarify my issue.
On left pannel, you have a list of filters based on current categories child, and attributes.
I want to change the way this pannel works, to add ALL categories. Not only parent and child, but also all the others categories and their children. Exactly what you see when you do a reseach. You aren't limited to one category, but you can see all (in which you searched product is, indeed. Here, I want this for all products).

Answer (score 0):

You can filter products by category with:

```
->addCategoryFilter($cat)
```

OR

```
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $catIDs))
```

Comment: Thanks, can you lead me on what file I need to edit to add this, please ?

Comment: I don't just want to filter products by categories.
I want to add to the filter list, all categories, exactly like when you do a research.

Comment: @user1745154 You need to edit where you are getting the product collection for the category.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm beeing misunderstood.
I'm talking about the block, on the left, where you can choose color, or whathever, are you too ?
I'm sorry because I don't understand where I can edit this.